# Options_from_collection_for_select - NoMethodError Or ArgumentError - how add properly argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, nomethoderror

In `Rails console` when I write Something like:
`City.human_attribute_name("model")` it's work correctly, a return value, but when I try to use it in `.haml` in `Options_from_collection_for_select` I have error.

```
= select_tag("select_tag", options_from_collection_for_select(@searchesForSelectTag, "name", 'human_attribute_name("model")', params[:select_tag]), {:include_blank => ' '})
```

NoMethodError: `` undefined method `human_attribute_name("model")' for #<Class:0x00007fdb90dd1198> Did you mean?  human_attribute_name ``

`@searchesForSelectTag` - this is array of classes name (eg. User, City, Car...).

When I try like only that : `"human_attribute_name"` I have ArgumentError:
`wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)`

How can I add argument "model" to method `human_attribute_name` in `Options_from_collection_for_select` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a string, you can pass a method call on a class:

```
= select_tag("select_tag", options_from_collection_for_select(@searchesForSelectTag, "name", City.human_attribute_name("model"), params[:select_tag]), {:include_blank => ' '})
```

Update

I found another solution with dynamic classes. You can try to experiment something with this.

```
<%= select_tag("select_tag", options_for_select(@searchesForSelectTag.map { |item| [item.name, item.class.human_attribute_name("model")] }, params[:select_tag]), {:include_blank => ' '}) %>
```

Comment: In here ```City.human_attribute_name("model")```   I want something like iteration class models:
```
City.human_attribute_name("model")
Person.human_attribute_name("model")
NextModel.human_attribute_name("model")
```
```@searchesForSelectTag``` is array with models (eg. ```City```, ```Person``` ...)

Comment: The 'human_attribute_name' method only works on the class so you have to distinguish between them somehow

Comment: Maybe I wrote incomprehensibly:
@searchesForSelectTag is array with model CLASS (eg. City, Person ...)  - that are classess.